# Probability of balloons with ratio

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

I solved this like this:

Total balloons$=1+5=6$

So the required probability is $\frac{3}{6} =0.5$

Is this correct? Can someone please say?

Comment: Are you told that there are exactly $6$ blue balloons in the bag? If not, then the probability depends on how many baloons there are in the bag, as outlined in tommik's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the selection is made without replacement, the probability changes with $k$

Your solution is correct only if $k=1$

In the bag there is a total of $6k$ balls with $k$ *blue* and $5k$ *other colour*

The probability to get *at least* one blue is the complement of having no blue in 3 selections, that is

$$1-\frac{\binom{5k}{3}}{\binom{6k}{3}}=1-\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{(5k-1)(5k-2)}{(6k-1)(6k-2)}$$

with $k\geq 1$